# Set first column as Date for all sheets except the first sheet

Tags: c#, epplus

My code generates 7 sheets which I am putting in the Excel Workbook. What I am trying to do is set first column as Date for all the sheets except for the first one. Below is what I've been trying but it does not seem to work. The date being displayed is some random number like 43,349.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            var sheetName = i < sheetNames.Count
            ? sheetNames[i]
            : String.Format("Sheet{0}", sheetNames.Count - i);
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

            ws.Cells["A1"]
                .LoadFromDataTable(i == 0 ? Transpose(ds.Tables[i].Copy()).DefaultView.ToTable() : ds.Tables[i],
                    true, TableStyles.Medium1);
            ws.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
            ws.Column(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            ws.Cells["A:H"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add "if" statement. If i > 0 then setup the date:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            var sheetName = i < sheetNames.Count
               ? sheetNames[i]
               : String.Format("Sheet{0}", sheetNames.Count - i);
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(i == 0 
                     ? Transpose(ds.Tables[i].Copy()).DefaultView.ToTable()
                     : ds.Tables[i],true, TableStyles.Medium1);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                 ws.Cells["A:H"] = "yyyy-mm-dd";
                 ws.Column(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
            }
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

        }
```

Comment: Tried using if, still did not work. It keeps generating number format. something like 43,349

Comment: Did you tied this option:  ws.Cells[1,10].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd"; ?

Comment: Ok, I figured out. I removed the last line of Numberformat and put it before if()  and that worked. Turns out, it was applying the date but that last line used to convert the date back to number format.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the last line of Numberformat and put it before if() and that worked. Turns out, it was applying the date but that last line used to convert the date back to number format.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        var sheetName = i < sheetNames.Count
           ? sheetNames[i]
           : String.Format("Sheet{0}", sheetNames.Count - i);
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(i == 0 
                 ? Transpose(ds.Tables[i].Copy()).DefaultView.ToTable()
                 : ds.Tables[i],true, TableStyles.Medium1);
        ws.Cells["A:H"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";
        if (i > 0)
        {
             ws.Cells[1,10] = "yyyy-mm-dd";
             ws.Column(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        }
        ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();


    }
```